# Unable to connect to HBase table using Java

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I am trying to connect to Hbase (version: 1.2.0) deployed on a different machine. I am using Eclipse and below is the code that I have written:

```
HTable table = null;
Configuration configuration = HBaseConfiguration.create();
configuration.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "192.168.0.191");
configuration.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
FilterList list = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL);
table = new HTable(configuration, hbaseTable);
```

Below are the dependencies I have added in pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

On running the code, I am getting the below exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.addDeprecations([Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration$DeprecationDelta;)V
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.util.ConfigUtil.addDeprecatedKeys(ConfigUtil.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.util.ConfigUtil.loadResources(ConfigUtil.java:42)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.<clinit>(JobConf.java:119)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:810)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:48)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.UserProvider.<clinit>(UserProvider.java:56)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionKey.<init>(HConnectionKey.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager.getConnectionInternal(ConnectionManager.java:298)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:184)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:150)
    at HbaseConnection.createConnection(HbaseConnection.java:34)
    at HbaseConnection.main(HbaseConnection.java:22)
```

I have gone through various links related to similar problem but I could not find any working solution. Can somebody help with the issue in my configuration or in my code?

Comment: Seems like you have a dependency conflict. Might be related to `hadoop-common:3.1.0` and `hadoop-core:1.2.0`. They probably need to be on the same major version.

Comment: no need to use hadoop  jar  change them  to habse -server jar

Comment: You don't need either of the Hadoop dependencies if you just want to talk to HBase. Also where did you get your versions from? Use the versions that correspond to what's installed on your cluster.

Comment: @BenWatson...thanks for your solution, it worked for me. You can post your comment as an answer and I shall accept the same. Thanks once again!!